# List of sysadmin/scaling/infrastructure specific conferences

Tags: untagged

Does anyone know a list of conferences/events that might be worth visiting for sysadmins, sytem architects,...?

What comes to my mind when thinking of some events that might be worth a visit for people from the sysadmin section:

- http://www.usenix.org/event/lisa09/
- http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix09/
- http://www.usenix.org/events/nsdi09/
- http://www.usenix.org/events/sec09/
- http://en.oreilly.com/velocity2009
- http://opensourcebridge.org/
- http://www.netways.de/english/osdc/y2009/
- http://www.sans.org/sans2009/
- http://www.ukuug.org/events/spring2009/
- http://www.interop.com/lasvegas/
- http://www.vmworld.com/community/conferences/2009/
- http://fsoss.senecac.on.ca/2009/
- http://en.oreilly.com/oscon2009
- http://sc09.supercomputing.org/
- http://www.interop.com/newyork/

Are you aware of any other events?

Answer (score 2):

SAGE-AU have an annual conference: http://www.sage-au.org.au/display/conf/Home.