# What do you look for in a technical conference?

Tags: untagged

Until this past year, I had never been to a technical conference. I had the good fortune to be able to go to [LISA09](http://www.usenix.org/events/lisa09/), and after seeing the value of the training offered there, I decided that tech conferences were worth my time.

LISA happens once a year. It's big and it's expensive, but the experience is amazing. There are [lots of other tech conferences](https://serverfault.com/questions/21139/list-of-sysadmin-scaling-infrastructure-specific-conferences) to pick from if you can't get to LISA, but those are still large and expensive, in many cases.

To try to offer another alternative, the NJ chapter of the [League of Professional System Administrators](http://www.lopsa.org) is creating [a local community-type conference](http://www.lopsanj.org/confannouncement.html).

Right now, we're building our itinerary for the conference, and we're looking for ideas. 
It's early enough in the process that you can help. Let us know what you look for, and what you'd like to see.

The conference we're scheduling is short (overnight) and cheap (~ $400), and meant for local sysadmins. What would you look for in a conference like that.

Also, make sure to talk to any NJ/NY sysadmins that you know, and tell them about us!

**[EDIT]**

This isn't, as far as I can tell, spam. If someone can drop a comment and let me know why it would be flagged as such, I'll happily take down the question, if the complaint is valid. I just want to know what sysadmins look for in a conference. I've only been to one, and I was spoiled, because it was the biggest and the best, from everything I've heard.

Comment: Once I find our survey results with data of what IT folks in our region wished to learn about I'll post it.  I don't know why this question is getting down voted, weird!  +1

Comment: hmm princeton that's only like an hour away i'd be interested in hearing what you come up with for an itinerary

Comment: I think it's a good question, should gather some interesting information. My guess would be that someone has marked it as spam because you mention your own conference, but I think that's a valid part of the question, not spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [linux.conf.au HOWTO](http://wiki.linux.org.au/Ctte/LCA_HOWTO).

LCA is one of the largest community run tech conferences in the region, and has a league of devoted followers.